# Bloquear acesso a um caminho URL ou pasta do sistema

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Oi, estou querendo bloquear o acesso da parte administrativa do meu site e liberar para somente alguns ips. Eu consigo fazer isso usando o `.htacess` bem tranquilo mas o problema é que eu tenho o módulo adminstrativa e o módulo frontend e o `.htaccess` da pasta web bloqueia todo o sistema e não só o administrativo. Queria saber como fazer para ele bloquear acesso pela url ou a pasta admin. Tentei usar o `.htaccess` e o `.htpasswd` na pasta de login mas não rolou.

Alguém que já passou por isso tem alguma idéia?

Answer (score 1):

Com a diretiva `access_control` da configuração de segurança do Symfony é bem fácil fazer isso.

Veja alguns exemplos [nesse artigo](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html) do próprio site do Symfony:

```
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER_IP, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER_HOST, host: symfony\.com$ }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER_METHOD, methods: [POST, PUT] }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Em cada uma das entradas da diretiva `access_control` é possível inserir quatro configurações:

- `path` (que define por meio de qual caminho a parte administrativa é acessível)
- `ip` ou `ips` (que define quais IPs têm acesso à parte administrativa)
- `host` (que define por meio de qual host a parte administrativa é acessível)
- `methods` (que define os métodos permitidos na parte administrativa)

Você também pode colocar uma expressão por meio da diretiva `allow_if` (por exemplo, `allow_if: "'127.0.0.1' == request.getClientIp() or has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')"`) e até forçar que os acessos à seção administrativa sejam feitos por meio de HTTPS (usando `requires_channel: https`).

Comment: massa, Isso funciona para o symfony 1.4?

Comment: Acredito que não. Vi a configuração de segurança do Symfony 1.4 e ela é bem crua: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/08-Security. Talvez seja uma boa pensar no upgrade da versão do Symfony no seu sistema, já que a segurança é tão crucial e ele está construído em cima de uma versão que não é mais mantida – portanto, potencialmente insegura.

Comment: verdade disso eu sei. é que eu precisei fazer um sisteminha com um framework feito em base do symfony 1.4 aqui na empresa. Ai não conseguirei fazer outro framework da empresa na versão 2.0 ou 3.0 por falta de tempo. Mas vou ver o que consigo na versão 1.4

Comment: Talvez seja uma boa colocar a seção administrativa em um virtual host separado e colocar as regras de acesso lá, como IPs permitidos, lá. Se achar que é uma boa ideia, me fale que eu coloco uma outra resposta.